# XML timer in DrawRect Screen

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, timer, drawrect

My Game uses `DrawRect`. It divided into 2 parts. the another part is `null` so it views nothing. since it view nothing i just wanted to insert an **XML** which is a **timer**. is it possible? I cant find a right solution for this one

here's my code on `drawRect:`

```
RectF rect = new RectF(0,0,width,height);

    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, rect, null);
```

Thanks for any help/suggestion and also for your time.